# 'php-win.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: php, exec

I am using windows , wamp , php5.4.12.
the path of the php is added in the systems environments
The IUSER has read and execute permission to cmd.exe

from cmd.exe I can run php, php.exe, php-win, php-win.exe, so I do not think there are a problem with the path environment

I am trying to run the following command

```
exec("php background.php > testoutput.php 2>&1 & echo $!", $output);
```

I tried for php, php.exe, php-win, php-win.exe, but I still get the following message

```
'php-win.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

Comment: set environment variables for your php

Comment: @Ritesh OP reckons they are, if you read.

Comment: @GrantThomas oh yes, just missed. but it's related to environment variable only or may be the binary 'php-win.exe' is missing from the directory

Comment: @Ritesh the enviroment is set for the dircetory and the directory has both php.exe and php-win.exe

Comment: The problem is solved... I have restarted the server couple of times and it works now